# sending files and body to nodeJS using fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch

how can I send a request to the server (rest) with files and somebody?
what I've tried so far:

```
func = async(event)=> {
   const body = { city_id: 8 }
   const filesToServer = new FormData();
   Object.values(event.files).forEach(file => filesToServer.append(file.name, file));
   myreqFunction(path, [...filesToServer, body]);
}
```

Comment: What results are you getting now, and what results should they be instead?

Comment: it doesn't recognize the files as files

Comment: What sort of output are you getting and where that tells you it doesn't recognize the files as files? You should [edit] these details to your question body.

Comment: @alejandroFernandez try `event.target.files.forEach` intead of  `Object.values(event.files).forEach`